# python mock patch how to do it

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I have a utility class A. Then a implementation class B which uses a method a() from class A. Now I want to unit test class B. But I want to replace the a() that it uses with a mock one.
How can I do that with mock/patch?

Here is what I have tried, none of it worked:

```
@mock.patch(MODULE_B_PATH.A)
def test(mock_A):
    mock_A.a.return_value = ""
    new B().run()

@mock.patch(MODULE_A_PATH):
def test(mock_A):
    mock_A.a.return_value = ""
    new B().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

i found every thing I want here:
http://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I always go back to [the author's site](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/getting-started.html) about `mock` library.